# LINQ - how to get n records from two tables?

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq

I have two tables, A and B, that are completely independent but both have a `time` column, which is of type `DateTime`.

What simple LINQ query do I need to write to get the 10 most recent (based on the `time` field) records from both tables, in one collection? For example, this query might return 7 records of A and 3 records of B - 10 records in total.

Comment: You need to join table B from table A. Take a look at this page: http://www.dotnetperls.com/join. It describes how joins can be achieved with LINQ.

Comment: Is there any other columns in table A and B that are common like "Time" column? Because you havent specifed the output record for the query you want to get. If both table are completely different you could create anonymous output record. If A and B have same columns than you can do Union.

Comment: Both tables *might* share a column, depending on how my database design goes. Can you show an example for both of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
var _result = tableA
              .Select(x => x.time)
              .Union(tableB.Select(y => y.time))
              .OrderByDescending(z => z.time)
              .Take(10);
```

SOURCE

- [C# 101 LiNQ Examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: `z.time` is unrecognized...? Also, this seems to return the `time` columns only, resulting in `_result` being an `IQueryable<DateTime>`. I don't want just the times, I want all the columns... The `time` should only be used to determine which 10 records get picked.

Comment: how about this `var _result = tableA
   .Union(tableB)
   .OrderByDescending(z => z.time)
   .Take(10);`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as `Union` only expects `tableA` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you X-Com example.
Let your tables store data for shipment to x-com base.
Let table A store recruits, and table B store items.
You want to display list of recruits and items that has been shipped to base sorting by date:

```
    //soldiers
    public class RowA
    {
        public long Id {get;set;}
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
    //items
    public class RowB
    {
        public long Id {get;set;}
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    List<RowA> TableA;
    List<RowB> TableB;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PrepareTestData();

        int uniqueId = 0;
        var result = (from a in TableA
                      //Map soldiers to anonymous
                      select new 
                      {
                          UniqueId = uniqueId++,
                          InnerId = a.Id,
                          Name = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                          Date = a.Date,
                      })
                    .Union(from b in TableB
                           select new 
                           {
                               UniqueId = uniqueId++,
                               InnerId = b.Id,
                               Name = b.ItemName,
                               Date = b.Date,
                           }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = result;

    }

    void PrepareTestData()
    {
        TableA = new List<RowA>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
            TableA.Add(new RowA
            {
                Id = i + 1,
                FirstName = "Name" + i,
                LastName = "Surname" + i,
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i)
            });
        TableB = new List<RowB>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            TableB.Add(new RowB
            {
                Id = j + 1,
                ItemName = "Laser pistol",
                Quantity = 7,
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-j)
            });
    }
```

You also can create class for output record:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PrepareTestData();

        int uniqueId = 0;
        var result = (from a in TableA
                      //Map soldiers to ShipmentReportItem
                      select new ShipmentReportItem
                      {
                          UniqueId = uniqueId++,
                          InnerId = a.Id,
                          Name = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                          Date = a.Date,
                      })
                    .Union(from b in TableB
                           select new ShipmentReportItem 
                           {
                               UniqueId = uniqueId++,
                               InnerId = b.Id,
                               Name = b.ItemName,
                               Date = b.Date,
                           }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
    }
```

One result class would be usefull for ASP.NET gridview if you need some checking or modyfing record. Then you will have easy acces to datasource item when you have defined type or else you would have to get dataitem type, then check its properties etc. get values from specific property.

And if your table B also stores people(have same columns) you dont need mapping because row struct will be the same.